Trying to build shared library by using third party libraries, cmake and vcpkg
File Structure
Just wanted to create a library using third party library, I am using Vcpkg and Cmake
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(Vcpkg)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)  
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)  

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp include/*.hpp)
add_library(Vcpkg SHARED ${SOURCES})
add_library(vcpkg::engine ALIAS Vcpkg)

target_include_directories(Vcpkg
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

add_executable(akash ${SOURCES})

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0 -coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS   "-coverage -lgcov")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )

target_compile_features(akash PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(akash
    PRIVATE 
        vcpkg::engine
        fmt::fmt 
        spdlog::spdlog
)

Error
1/5] Scanning /home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/src/main.cpp for CXX dependencies
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi 
/usr/bin/c++ -DVcpkg_EXPORTS -I/home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/include -I/home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/src -g -O0 -coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g -std=gnu++20 -fPIC -fdiagnostics-color=always -E -x c++ /home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/src/main.cpp -MT CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi -MD -MF CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi.d -fmodules-ts -fdeps-file=CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi -fdeps-target=CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o -fdeps-format=p1689r5 -o CMakeFiles/Vcpkg.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi.i
/home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: fmt/color.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <fmt/color.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [Makefile:10: debug] Error 1

ninja.log
# ninja log v6
15  26803   1719332434965250296 CMakeFiles/akash.dir/src/main.cpp.o 384a56197d066769
3   14  1719332434953250355 /home/akashdiphazra/Downloads/Vcpkg/build/linux-debug/CMakeFiles/akash.dir/CXXModules.json  4879662838ccf47d
3   14  1719332434953250355 CMakeFiles/akash.dir/CXX.dd 4879662838ccf47d
3   14  1719332434953250355 CMakeFiles/akash.dir/src/main.cpp.o.modmap  4879662838ccf47d
1   2305    1719333409493404124 build.ninja 430dfc98276d9b78
4   549 1719332374774547644 CMakeFiles/akash.dir/src/main.cpp.o.ddi 8ee06fab8c85eae4
53  4480    1719333409493404124 build.ninja 430dfc98276d9b78

Error happens whenever I tried to debug this. It compiles without the vcpkg but when I was trying to add third party libraries using vcpkg , it fails.
it compiles Sucessfully when
Root Dir
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.28)

project(Vcpkg)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)

# Add sub directories
include_directories(include)
add_subdirectory(src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

src/CMakeList.txt
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0 -coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS   "-coverage -lgcov")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )

add_executable(akash main.cpp)
target_compile_features(akash PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(akash fmt::fmt spdlog::spdlog)

am i doing something wrong, i am new to Cmake build systems.

What is the full path to fmt/color.h on your computer?

It was actually in build vcpkg_installed folder. i added the vcpkg.cmake according to documentation it should have detected include file. I worked when I didn't try to make any shared library from it. All vcpkg packages are inside vcpkg_installed folder inside build directories.

Are you using the vcpkg toolchain file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration

The error message you got is about Vcpkg library (note on Vcpkg.dir part of the path). You didn't link that library with fmt::fmt. (You link with fmt::fmt only the executable akash). Actually, including main.cpp file into the library looks wrong. Normally, only executables have main function.

Yes i added the toolchian file in CMake Presets which generate build file for me. that's not the issue.

I agree with Tsyvarev in the comment. The problem is that you have created a target/library called Vcpkg which using globbing for sources and which is not linked with fmt.
You probably want to remove main.cpp from SOURCES (list(REMOVE_ITEM ...)) and only have main.cpp be connected with the akash target.
Depending on what SOURCES actually contains and requires to link you need to use target_link_libraries with the vcpkg::engine target just like you do it with the akash executable target

As you told i have some corrections.but still same error.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(Vcpkg)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

find_package(fmt REQUIRED)  
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)  

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(Vcpkg SHARED src/main.cpp)
add_library(vcpkg::engine ALIAS Vcpkg)

target_include_directories(Vcpkg
      PUBLIC
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/>
)

add_executable(akash src/main.cpp)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0 -coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS   "-coverage -lgcov")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )

target_link_libraries(Vcpkg PRIVATE fmt::fmt spdlog::spdlog)
target_compile_features(akash PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(akash PRIVATE vcpkg::engine)


add_library(Vcpkg SHARED src/main.cpp)   add_executable(akash src/main.cpp)   target_link_libraries(akash PRIVATE vcpkg::engine)  
does not make sense together. you shouldn't compile the same cpp file into different targets and then try to link those two together. I doubt you have the same error as before since the Vcpkg target should now build. However, the akash target will not build since it is not linking fmt::fmt since the dependency on it in Vcpkg is marked as PRIVATE. It will show a similar error but not the same.
